# Facebook Group Change from public to closed

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I want to change the settings of my group on Facebook from public to closed, and cannot find anywhere on Facebook where I can do this.

Answer (score 2):

To change your group's privacy as an admin:

1. Click  in the top right of the group > **Edit Group Settings**
2. Choose a new group privacy option under the Privacy section
3. Click Save

*Google is your friend!*

Comment: Help much appreciated